# Publishagent with sitecore 8.2 publishing service

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

For publishagent to auto publish Items that are in final state of workflow. I have made following changes in Config file:

```xml
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:02:00">
  <param desc="source database">master</param>
  <param desc="target database">web</param>
  <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
  <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
</agent>
```

Items are not getting published.While changing the mode to smart is publishing items. Does this publish agent works in incremental mode with sitecore 8.2 publishing service?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the combination publish agent/incremental/publish service. The development team at Sitecore is aware and it will probably be fixed in a next version.

As far as I know, there is no patch available yet.